# How do I line up this text and buttons inside of a Div?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to create these 4 divs stacked.  This layout will actually be the results of a JQuery iteration over a loop.

I'm not picky on how this is accomplished, but I'm trying to get buttons, or links or in this case spans to display on the right of each of these divs and then the text on the left.

I think the padding is dropping them down but I'm not sure how to get them to all line up?

I appreciate any assistance?

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align: center;
}

.container{
  width:100%;
}

.d{
  font-weight:bold;
  padding:7px 0px 7px 7px;
  font-size: em1;
  color: #55862d;
  border: 1px solid #6f6b68;
  width:100%;
  text-align: left;
  clear: both;
}


#dContainer{
  width:100%;
  padding-top:10px;
}

.dHeader{
  text-align: left;
  padding:1px 0px 1px 10px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

#dResults{
  padding-top: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

.bButton{
  color:#fff;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #55862d;
  padding:7px 7px 7px 7px;
  float:right;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
  <section id="dContainer">
  <div class="dHeader">Title</div>
  <div id="dResults">
    <div class="d">something A<span class="bButton">Click!</span></div>
    <div class="d">something b<span class="bButton">Click!</span></div>
    <div class="d">something c<span class="bButton">Click!</span></div>
    <div class="d">something d<span class="bButton">Click!</span></div>
  </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: can you provide your code at jsfiddle

Comment: Can't you just drop the floating and do `.d{position:relative} .bButton{position:absolute;right:0}` and go from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it should be enough to add a negative margin top to the buttons.

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align: center;
}

.container{
  width:100%;
}

.d{
  font-weight:bold;
  padding:7px 0px 7px 7px;
  font-size: em1;
  color: #55862d;
  border: 1px solid #6f6b68;
  width:100%;
  text-align: left;
  clear: both;
}


#dContainer{
  width:100%;
  padding-top:10px;
}

.dHeader{
  text-align: left;
  padding:1px 0px 1px 10px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

#dResults{
  padding-top: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

.bButton{
  color:#fff;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #55862d;
  padding:8px 7px 7px 7px;
  float:right;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: -7px;
}
```

```html
<section id="dContainer">
  <div class="dHeader">Title</div>
  <div id="dResults">
    <div class="d">something A<span class="bButton">Click!</span></div>
    <div class="d">something b<span class="bButton">Click!</span></div>
    <div class="d">something c<span class="bButton">Click!</span></div>
    <div class="d">something d<span class="bButton">Click!</span></div>
  </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm sure there are other answers on here that will work but that did it, super simple THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block` to your divs `.d`:

You can also set  `margin-right` to the `span`

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align: center;
}

.container{
  width:100%;
}

.d{
  display: inline-block;

  font-weight:bold;
  padding:7px 0px 7px 7px;
  font-size: em1;
  color: #55862d;
  border: 1px solid #6f6b68;
  width:100%;
  text-align: left;
  clear: both;
}


#dContainer{
  width:100%;
  padding-top:10px;
}

.dHeader{
  text-align: left;
  padding:1px 0px 1px 10px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

#dResults{
  padding-top: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

.bButton{
  margin-right: 6px;
  color:#fff;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #55862d;
  padding:7px 7px 7px 7px;
  float:right;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
  <section id="dContainer">
  <div class="dHeader">Title</div>
  <div id="dResults">
    <div class="d">something A<span class="bButton">Click!</span></div>
    <div class="d">something b<span class="bButton">Click!</span></div>
    <div class="d">something c<span class="bButton">Click!</span></div>
    <div class="d">something d<span class="bButton">Click!</span></div>
  </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Tell me for more help

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align: center;
}

.container{
  width:100%;
}

.d{
  font-weight:bold;
  padding:7px 0px 7px 7px;
  font-size: em1;
  color: #55862d;
  border: 1px solid #6f6b68;
  width:100%;
  text-align: left;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}


#dContainer{
  width:100%;
  padding-top:10px;
}

.dHeader{
  text-align: left;
  padding:1px 0px 1px 10px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

#dResults{
  padding-top: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

.bButton{
  height: 100%;
  /* padding:7px; */
  padding: 1px 7px 7px 7px;
  float:right;
  clear: both;
  
}
```

```html
  <section id="dContainer">
  <div class="dHeader">Title</div>
  <div id="dResults">
    <div class="d">something A<span class="bButton">Click!</span></div>
    <div class="d">something b<span class="bButton">Click!</span></div>
    <div class="d">something c<span class="bButton">Click!</span></div>
    <div class="d">something d<span class="bButton">Click!</span></div>
  </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create it using flex. No need of float.

Update these styles

```
.bButton{
  color:#fff;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #55862d;
  padding:7px 7px 7px 7px;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.d {
  font-weight:bold;
  padding:7px 0px 7px 7px;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #55862d;
  border: 1px solid #6f6b68;
  width:100%;
  display: flex;     
}
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align: center;
}

.container{
  width:100%;
}

.bButton{
  color:#fff;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #55862d;
  padding:7px 7px 7px 7px;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.d {
  font-weight:bold;
  padding:7px 0px 7px 7px;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #55862d;
  border: 1px solid #6f6b68;
  width:100%;
  display: flex;     
}



#dContainer{
  width:100%;
  padding-top:10px;
}

.dHeader{
  text-align: left;
  padding:1px 0px 1px 10px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

#dResults{
  padding-top: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
  <section id="dContainer">
  <div class="dHeader">Title</div>
  <div id="dResults">
    <div class="d">something A<span class="bButton">Click!</span></div>
    <div class="d">something b<span class="bButton">Click!</span></div>
    <div class="d">something c<span class="bButton">Click!</span></div>
    <div class="d">something d<span class="bButton">Click!</span></div>
  </div>
  </section>
```